# How to display a warning when an uploaded image is too small?

Tags: images, filters, uploads, warnings

I want to display a warning when a user uploads an image with too low a resolution. I don't want to block the upload, just give a warning.

The only option I see is `wp_handle_upload_prefilter`, but there you can only return an error which blocks the upload.

```php
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', function ( $file ) {
    if ( str_contains( $file['type'], 'image' ) ) {
        $image = getimagesize( $file['tmp_name'] );
        if ( $image[0] < 1200 ) {
            //How do I display this warning but not block uploading?        
            $file['error'] = 'Image too small!';
        }
    }

    return $file;
} );
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I'm struggling with the same issue.